# Por que en ocasiones mi pagina web no cargan los recursos CSS, JS, y/o IMG?

Tags: angularjs, spring, java-ee

tengo un proyecto de una aplicación web en el que esta totalmente bien pero en ocasiones ocurren problemas en el que no cargan algunos CSS, JS y/o IMG.

**Tecnologias:**

- JAVA EE
- Spring 4.3
- Angular 1.2

**Problemas:**

1. Esta es mi pagina tal cual como se debe ver (sin error alguno):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Aveces no cargan los CSS y/o JS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Yo uso Angular1.2 para SPA(Single page application) para hacer un cambio de contenido dinamico y aveces no cargan los recursos CSS y/o JS y por consecuente no cambia el contenido dinamico.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**POSDATA:**

Me gustaría que me colaboraran la verdad no encuentro la razón de por que pasa esto, en una de mis dudas no se si el problema sea usar Angular1.2 (por ser una versión antigua) o por algún otro error ejecutando el servidor con JAVA/Spring y tambien con Thymeleaf, Gracias.

Comment: podría ser quen intentes acceder a los recursos antes de que estén disponibles y un error puede desencadenar en otro. prueba a encapsular tu fichero javascript en `$(function() {  /* aqui tu javascript */  })`. También asegúrate de que las llamadas a los estilos se encuentran en la etiqueta `<head>` y que los scripts están al final antes de cerrar la etiqueta `</body>`, importando primero JQuery y despues tus propios scripts

Comment: Exacto estan tal cual como lo dices mis recursos CSS estan el <head> y los JS estan al final del <body> y con JQuery linkeado primero que todos los JS mios, entiendo que si no carga el jquery los otros no funcionara pero el problema no esta en que demore en cargar un JS el problema esta en que si entro a la pagina y no encuentra el recurso se queda asi y no vuelve a cargar (osea el problema no es de tiempo de carga sino de que NO CARGA)

Comment: es que es muy raro por que no te lanza error, prueba a clickar en el origen del "error" en los ficheros, en la parte superior derecha del error a ver si te reconoce el fichero y esta completo. Así de primeras diria que puede ser el dichoso CORS pero claro no tiene sentido que a veces te cargue y otras no...

Comment: Clickeé el error y me redirige al Network en el que el fichero esta vacio y aparece Status : failed net::error failed_HTTP_Response. **Imagen 1 :** https://ibb.co/diVrao
**Imagen 2 :** https://ibb.co/edHto8

Comment: comprueba que la ruta es correcta y si tira de algun servidor mejor descargalo y usalo desde tu propio servidor

Comment: Exacto esta totalmente correcta la ruta y no uso CDN, esta todo en el mismo servidor. (La ruta esta totalmente bien, si no estuviera bien no cargaria aveces si - aveces no, en cambio no cargaría nunca), no se que pasara :/, siempre me he aguantado hacer los proyectos asi, osea me toca recargar la pagina 1, 2 o 3 veces para estar seguro que cargaron bien los recursos llegue a pensar si fuera problemas de Cache o algo asi y configuraba mi proyecto el cache : false, borro el cache del navegador, etc etc etc y nada